# width or height of child element doesn't change in CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my DOM:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
hello
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        height: 10%;
        width: 10;
    }
```

What I want to do is to re-size the height and width of the `TD` element using percentage. But this code doesn't work. I understand that the size of a child element will inherit the size of it's parent element. So `TD` will inherit the size from `TABLE` and then `TABLE` from `BODY` or `HTML` parent elements. My code doesn't do that. But if I do `width: 10%;` on `TABLE`, then it gets 10% of the width of the `BODY/HTML` element. Same as with the `height: 10%`. But why doesn't it work on `TD` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`td` tags are forced to take up all of the remaining space in their parent.

So, your `width: 10%;` is completely ignored by the layout.

See this non-working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/R5uRW/1/).

But, if we add some `display: inline-block;` to the `td`, then it fixes the problem.

See this (now) working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/R5uRW/3/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add another td tag, and give it a width of 90%

```
<table>
<tr class="tr1">
<td class=td1>
hello
</td>
<td class="td2"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr2">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td.td1 {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
}
td.td2{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 90%;
}
tr.tr1{
    height:10%;
}
tr.tr2{
    height:90%;
}
```

For the height, you will need to add another tr row, and give it a 90%. Give the first row a 10% height like you wanted to do with the td - http://jsfiddle.net/R5uRW/6/